# Python Pandas data frame with column value as a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe DF in the following format, first row is the column name

```
name   val1    val2
 A      1       2
 B      3       4
```

How to convert to the following data frame format

```
name    map
 A      {val1:1,val2:2}
 B      {val1:3,val2:4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with `to_dict()` method of dataframe.

```
x['map']=x[['val1','val2']].to_dict(orient='records')
```